# Database connectivity issue and inserting values in database using php

Tags: database, insert, phpmyadmin

this is the code im using .the database name, table name, username,password are correct. but it does'nt insert any value in the table in phpMyadmin using this code. 
I dont know whats wrong . please help :(

```
<?
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("game", $con);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `game`.`gametbl` (`ID`, `name`, `score`) VALUES (NULL, 'jjjjjjjj', '66')");


echo"success" ;
mysql_close($con);
<?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes, its not the fix but at least it may display an error message and error code to you so you get a little help idenfifying what is actually wrong.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if ( ! mysql_select_db("game", $con) ) {
    die( 'Cannot connect to the game database' );
}

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `game`.`gametbl` (`ID`, `name`, `score`) VALUES (NULL, 'jjjjjjjj', '66')");

if ( ! $result ) {
    echo 'Failed with error ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error();
} else {
    echo "success";
}
mysql_close($con);
```